# How do I stay at the same scroll position while adding items in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qscrollarea

I have a QScrollArea which contains a QWidget which has a QVBoxLayout. I want to implement an infinite scroll whereby when you get 80% to the bottom of the scroll, it loads more items so you can scroll even more.

The problem is that when I get to the 80% and I try to add more items to the QVBoxLayout, all the items get shifted up so that you see all the new items. How do I get the QScrollArea to stay in the same relative place while the new items are added?

Comment: Do those items need to be widgets? Have you considered using a QAbstractListModel and a QListView? That would scale better in case you have a lot of items.

Answer (score 2):

Save the absolute position before adding the items, then restore it after adding the items. Like so (untested). The default behavior apparently preserves the relative position and that's precisely what you don't want.

Note that this works only if you append items.

```
void code() {
  //...
  QScrollBar * bar; 
  const int savedPos = bar->value();
  // add items here
  bar->setValue(savedPos);
  //...
}
```

Comment: This is an untested comment as well, but wouldnt the bar be unreliable after adding N new items? What about just check the position of a child widget and rescrolling to that last widget again?

Comment: This idea doesnt work. Think about what it means. Its saying essentially that the slider should stay in the same place on the bar. This is incorrect because since new items are added below, the location of the old items moves up, therefore, the slider should move up too.

Comment: Perhaps I've done it a bit over the top. The reverse will work, then: saving and restoring the absolute position. I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is along the lines of jdi's comment: I used the QScrollBar's value to get the current position of the QScrollArea, then I looped through the QLayout and checked the QLayoutItem->geometry()  of each child to see which child was closest to the top. Then, after I inserted, I did QWidget->geometry() to get the height of that item followed by QScrollBar->setValue() to scroll to that location.